# facebook and google plus user verification in server side with the access token send from javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-plus, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

Am using google plus and facebook javascript sign in feature for my website. I am able to get the user details and the access token in javascript. I want to validate the user in server side(java) also. Is it possible to do the same with the help of **access token** which i can send as an ajax request?

Comment: For Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#debug

Answer (score 1):

With Google+, the preferred method is to use the client to get a one-time code and to provide this code to the server. The server then exchanges it for an access_token as part of verifying there is no malicious activity going on.

See https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow for details.